# Why aren't my ~/.login_conf settings respected when ssh into FreeBSD?

Tags: ssh, freebsd, login, locale

I connect to a local FreeBSD server (which I administer) via ssh from my laptop. I have a stock FreeBSD 11.2 `/etc/login.conf` file. I have appended the following to my `~/.login_conf` file:

```
:me \
    :charset=UTF-8:\
    :lang=en_CA.UTF-8:
```

Reading the FreeBSD handbook, [22.2. *Using Localization*](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/using-localization.html), I would expect that my `LANG` and other locale variables would be set for me when I connect via ssh.

When I connect, I expect to see:

```
% locale
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Instead, I see this:

```
% locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

It looks to me as if my `~/.login_conf` file is not being respected.

Why is my `~/.login_conf` file is not being respected? How can I make it have effect?

Some further information: yes, i have run [`cap_mkdb`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/cap_mkdb/) after changing my login configuration. It gave no error nor success message. This is how my configuration files look:

```
% ls -lF /etc/login* ~/.login*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1853 Jun 21  2018 /etc/login.access
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   6790 Jun 21  2018 /etc/login.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  16384 Sep  2 16:41 /etc/login.conf.db
-rw-r--r--  1 meee  meee     392 Aug 22 01:04 /home/meee/.login
-rw-r--r--  1 meee  meee     214 Sep  2 16:23 /home/meee/.login_conf
-rw-r--r--  1 meee  meee   16384 Sep  2 16:23 /home/meee/.login_conf.db
-rw-r--r--  1 meee  meee     214 Sep  2 16:11 /home/meee/.login_conf~
```

I understand I need to start a new session to have the new locale settings take effect. I understand that exiting an ssh session on the FreeBSD server, then re-connecting to FreeBSD via ssh, starts a new login session. So I expect this is enough to let the `~/.login_conf` take effect. But it doesn't seem to work.

The following command makes `locale` return the correct result for the rest of the current session:

```
% LANG=en_CA.UTF-8; export LANG ; MM_CHARSET=UTF-8; export MM_CHARSET
```

It is a workaround, but I would prefer for `~/.login_conf` to work reliably.

My complete `~/.login_conf` file is:

```
# $FreeBSD: releng/11.2/share/skel/dot.login_conf 77995 2001-06-10 17:08:53Z ache $
#
# see login.conf(5)
#
#me:\
#       :charset=iso-8859-1:\
#       :lang=de_DE.ISO8859-1:

:me \
    :charset=UTF-8:\
    :lang=en_CA.UTF-8:
```

[Update: added complete `~/.login_conf` file contents, improved wording of `cap_mkdb` description.]

Comment: If you change `:me` to `me:`, does that help?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yes! In fact it fixes the problem. Please submit this as an answer, and I will upvote it. I improved the question to point more clearly to this being the answer. Clearly, I misread the example in the standard `~/.login_conf` file.